# Drupal 7 render an array in Block_view

Tags: arrays, drupal-7, render

I want to render an array and print the output as Block[content]. There is either my Foreach or the way I use $item array or $row that is wrong. I will appreciate your help.

```
 function produkt_block_view($delta = '')
{

  $block = array();

   $list = produkt_produkliste(1);    
   $items = array();
   foreach ($list as $row) {
     $items[1] = $row->uri;
     $items[2] = $row->title;
     $items[3] = $row->body_value;
   }


  switch($delta) {
    case 'produkt' :
      $block['content'] = '<a href="/19">';
      $block['content'] .= '<img class="pimg" src="'.$row->uri.'" alt="Se alle vores filter elementer her">';          
      $block['content'] .= '<p class="pname">"'.$row->title.'"</p>';
      $block['content'] .= '<p>"'.$row->body_value.'"</p>';      
      $block['content'] .= theme ('item_list',array('items' => $items, 'type' => 'ol',   'attribute' => 'produkt'));      
      break;   
    }

    return $block;
  }
```

Comment: The result i get is the HTML I define in Block[content] without the values of $row->uri, $row->title, $row->body_value. They are empty. And it means I have done something wrong :)

Comment: Could you paste content of $list variable?